# DataTable: Get Max Value Using LINQ With Criteria Field (GroupBy)

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable structured like this:

> username | price
>
> "jack"        .01
>
> "jack"        .02
>
> "mary"       .03
>
> "mary"       .04

How can I use LINQ on the DataTable to return the MAX PRICE FOR JACK (ex: .02)?

Code to setup the table (can ignore).

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("username");
tbl.Columns["username"].DataType = typeof(string);

tbl.Columns.Add("price");
tbl.Columns["price"].DataType = typeof(double);

DataRow r = tbl.NewRow();
r["username"] = "jack"; r["price"] = .01;
tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        
r = tbl.NewRow();
r["username"] = "jack"; r["price"] = .02;
tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        
r = tbl.NewRow();
r["username"] = "mary"; r["price"] = .03;
tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        
r = tbl.NewRow();
r["username"] = "mary"; r["price"] = .04;
tbl.Rows.Add(r);
```

This is where I get stuck.  Want to return one row for Jack with his highest price (ex: ".02").

```
var result =
    from row in tbl.AsEnumerable() 
    where (string) row["username"] == "jack"
    group row by new {usernameKey = row["username"]} into g  
    select new
    {
        //WHAT IS THE LINQ SYNTAX TO USE HERE?    
        jackHighestPrice = g.Max(x => x.price); //This doesn't work, VS doesn't see the "price" field as strongly typed (not sure why).
    };

//This should display Jack's highest price.  
MessageBox.Show(result.First().jackHighestPrice.ToString());
```

I'm not sure how to get Visual Studio to recognize the "Price" field as strongly typed. Guessing it's related to the issue.

Of course, two queries will work (one to filter by username, then another to select Max but it's not as elegant.

Related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299573/722945).  Tried just about everything/looked all over but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: g.Max(x => x["price"]); or g.Max(x => x.Field<double>("price");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't access "price" that way since there's no `price` member on `DataRow`. Access it just like you're doing with `username` (by column name):

```
var result =
    from row in tbl.AsEnumerable() 
    where (string) row["username"] == "jack"
    group row by new {usernameKey = row["username"]} into g  
    select new
    { 
        jackHighestPrice = g.Max(x => x["price"])
    };
```

Of course you could simply do:

```
string max = tbl.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row["username"].ToString() == "jack")
        .Max(row => row["price"])
        .ToString();
```

Comment: That works great! Not sure how other examples can use strongly typed properties but that's for another day...

Answer (score 5):

Did you try:

```
var query = tbl.AsEnumerable().Where(tr => (string) tr["username"] == "jack")
               .Max(tr => (double) tr["price"]);
```

Comment: all these years didnt know you could cast columns like that instead of z.field<double>["RENT"] vs (double)["RENT"] so.... +1

Answer (score 3):

```
var result =
    from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
    where (string)row["username"] == "jack"
    let x = new { usernameKey = (string)row["username"], (double)price = row["price"] }
    group x by x.usernameKey into g
    select g.Max(x => x.price);
```

However, since you allow only one user, grouping is not necessary. Just select the maximum as @WorldIsRound suggests.

Comment: I like this a lot.  Wish I could choose two answers.

Comment: You can up vote any question or answer that you like by clicking the up-arrow.